# Prove by mathematical induction that $n^2 > n$ for all $n \geq 2$

Tags: inequality, induction, self-learning, formal-proofs

> Prove by mathematical induction that $n^2 > n$ for all $n \geq 2$.

My attempt:

When $n=2$

LHS , $2^2 =4$

RHS , $2$
 When $n=2$, LHS $>$ RHS

Assume true for $n=k$

$k^2>k$

RTP true for $n=k+1$

$(k+1)^2 > k + 1$

Proof

By assumption 
$k^2>k$
 Thus, $k^2 +2k +1 > k + 2k +1 $
$(k+1)^2 > (k+1) + 2k $
Since $k > 1$
$2k>2 $
Hence $(k+1) + 2k > k+1 $
Therefore $(k+1)^2 > k+1$

Hence by induction the statement is true

Comment: Could you please write down the whole proof so that we can tell you whether it is ok or not?

Comment: Okay np I'll hand write it and submit it since it's a bit long

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct, there is no problem with it. A more straightforward way to prove the statement directly without using induction simply is by multiplying the inequality $n>1$ by $n$.